# Not able to get extras from Intent passed from adapter?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pass information from an adapter that will give me information to build a tv show episode cardview.

Yet all of my values are returning as null.

Here is my adapter code (the code in question is in MyMenuItemClickListener in the 3rd case statement)

```
public class TvShowSeasonsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TvShowSeasonsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Season> seasonList;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvShowTitle,season, episodes;
    public ImageView thumbnail, overflow;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tvShowTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvShowTitle);
        season = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Season);
        episodes = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Episodes);
        thumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        overflow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.overflow);
    }
}


public TvShowSeasonsAdapter(Context mContext, List<Season> seasonList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.seasonList = seasonList;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.tvshow_seasoncard, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Season tvshowSeason = seasonList.get(position);
    holder.tvShowTitle.setText(tvshowSeason.getTvShowName());
    holder.season.setText("Season " + tvshowSeason.getSeasonNumber());
    holder.episodes.setText("No of Episodes :" + tvshowSeason.getEpisodeCount());

    // loading TV show poster  using Glide library
    Glide.with(mContext).load(tvshowSeason.getPosterPath()).into(holder.thumbnail);

    holder.overflow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showPopupMenu(holder.overflow, position);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Showing popup menu when tapping on 3 dots
 */
private void showPopupMenu(View view, int position) {
    // inflate menu
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_tvshowseasonsadapter, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener(position));
    popup.show();

}

/**
 * Click listener for popup menu items
 */
class MyMenuItemClickListener implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    int position;

    public MyMenuItemClickListener(int position) {
        this.position=position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Intent intent;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.go_to_Popular:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Go back to Popular", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                intent = new Intent(mContext,PopularActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Add to Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.back_to_favourites:
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Go to Favourites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                /*
                TODO - Need to make sure there is at least one favourite selected before allowing the
                the user to go to the favourite activity. */
                // Need to use mContext since in menu listener
                intent = new Intent(mContext, FavouriteActivity.class);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.view_episodes:
                intent = new Intent(mContext, WhereWazzaEpisodes.class);
                Intent intentContents = ((Activity) mContext).getIntent();
                int seasonForEpisodes = seasonList.get(position).getSeasonNumber();
                int amountOfEp = seasonList.get(position).getEpisodeCount();
                int tvShowId = intentContents.getIntExtra("favTvShowID",0);
                intent.putExtra("seasonNumber", seasonForEpisodes);
                intent.putExtra("tvShowId", tvShowId);
                intent.putExtra("episodeCount", amountOfEp);

                mContext.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            default:
        }
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return seasonList.size();
}
```

}

And here is the code for my activity in the onCreate method:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.episode_list);
    Intent intent=getIntent();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String tvShowID = extras.getString("favTvShowID");
    Log.d("TVSHOW_ID", tvShowID);
    String seasonNumber = extras.getString("seasonNumber");
    Log.d("TVSHOW_SEASONNUM", seasonNumber);
    String episodeCount = extras.getString("episodeCount");
    Log.d("TVSHOW_EPISODE", episodeCount);
```

I've tried both bundles and intents to try and see if there was any difference but they still return null.

Comment: the values on your list you mean?

Comment: I think in your extras is null . Once try with static data.

Comment: you getting any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try with

and make sure you are passing data by keeping log before

```
Log.e("checksendingdata",seasonForEpisodes+"||"+tvShowId+"||"+amountOfEp);
  intent.putExtra("seasonNumber", seasonForEpisodes);
  intent.putExtra("tvShowId", tvShowId);
  intent.putExtra("episodeCount", amountOfEp);
```

if logs in your android monitor showing nothing then its error in your passing data

if every thing is fine in setting intent extras  try this in your activity

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
int tvShowID=intent.getIntExtra("favTvShowID",0);
int seasonNumber=intent.getIntExtra("seasonNumber",0);
int episodeCount=intent.getIntExtra("episodeCount",0);
/// 0 mean to default values in that where nothing passes from intent it will take 0 value
```

Comment: I seem to be having problems getting the tvShowID in the adapter on this line: int tvShowId = intentContents.getIntExtra("favTvShowID",0); - Seems I can't access the value from the activity that starts the adapter

Comment: if your are sending integer then write as`int tvShowID=intent.getIntExtra("favTvShowID");
int seasonNumber=intent.getIntExtra("seasonNumber");
int episodeCount=intent.getIntExtra("episodeCount");`     edited code updated try with it in above